# How can I wrap or break this line of code?

Tags: java, word-wrap

I know people have probably asked this a thousand times before, but every time I try Netbeans tells me I am wrong.

```
    highestPoint = (initialVelocity * Math.sin(launchAngle) * t - 1/2 * g Math.sqrt(t));
```

I want to break it around even in the middle and center it with around the initalVelocity underneath.

[image: error here]

Comment: What exactly NetBeans is telling you? Can you post that message?

Comment: It is telling me there is a ) expected and ; expected

Comment: Please put exact error message in the question. Use [edit] option for that.

Comment: Also what are you trying to do at `- 1/2g math.sqrt(t));`? What is `g` suppose to mean? And remember that Java is case-sensitive so `math` is not the same as `Math`.

Comment: I detect a compilation error around '1/2g math.sqrt(t)', should it perhaps be '1/(2*g) * Math.sqrt(t)'? Also, your other 'math' call should also use 'Math'.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the Math tip. This is just a small part of a large project I am doing for one of my classes. g is 32 ft/sec^2 basically.

Comment: Before asking how to wrap it without causing compilation error, how about you get the one-liner to actually compile?

Comment: because it would be easier for me to read if I can wrap it Andreas, Thank you guys

Comment: But make it compile first, e.g. change `math` to `Math`, and `2g` to something that actually makes sense to the Java compiler.

Comment: And as @ErikNyström stated, your specific error is as a result of not having an operator like '*' in between the 'g' and Math.sqrt(t).

Comment: The error message is actually quiet explicit and on point: ***Cannot find symbol `math`***. Which is of course because you don't have anything by that name.

Comment: Are you referring to [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Maximum_height_of_projectile): `h = v * t * sin(θ) - ½ * g * pow(t, 2)`? Because if you are, then know that [`sqrt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) is [*square root*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root), not the power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is no errorneous code:

```
double highestPoint = (initialVelocity * Math.sin(launchAngle) * t - (1/2*g) * Math.sqrt(t));
```

**1.** Note that **Math** class is with the capital M

**2.** You cannot write simply 2g or 2x or any as a math formula. You have to use the * multiplication operator in **all** cases.

Actually I have really no idea what should that do. Would you share your secret? >,<

Comment: Its part of a larger project that is supposed to compute projectile motion for my java class in university and yes all of your guys comments worked perfectly between capitalizing Math to putting a * there. Thank you guys very much for the responses.

Comment: You are assuming `1/2g` means `1/(2*g)`, not `0.5*g`.

Comment: It depends ... I am not sure what he means. However your assumption seems better, so I edited it.

Comment: I believe OP is referring to [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Maximum_height_of_projectile): `h = v * t * sin(θ) - ½ * g * pow(t, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Maximum_height_of_projectile):

```
h = v * t * sin(θ) - ½ * g * pow(t, 2)
```

Then the correct Java expression is:

```
height = initialVelocity * t * Math.sin(launchAngle) - g * t * t / 2;
```

And you can split that anywhere over multiple lines, e.g.

```
height = (initialVelocity * Math.sin(launchAngle)
          - g * t / 2) * t;
```

Of course, you don't need `t`:

```
highestPoint = Math.pow(initialVelocity * Math.sin(launchAngle), 2) / 2 / g;
```